# LWC JS function not sending parameter to Apex method

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm learning Lightning web component and I was working on an assignment and got an issue.

I'm trying to pass a parameter from Lightning Web Component (LWC) JS function to Apex method and for some reason its not sending the parameter.

Here is the code

**HTML**

```
`<template>
    <lightning-card title="All Contacts">
        <lightning-input type="number" label="Number of Contact Records to Retrieve" onchange={numberOfContactChangeHandler}></lightning-input>
        <p>
            <lightning-button label="Get Contacts" onclick={getContacts}></lightning-button>
        </p>
        <ul>
            <template if:true={responseReceived}>
                <template for:each={contacts} for:item="contact">
                    <li key={contact.id}>
                        <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
                            <lightning-tile label={contact.LastName}>
                                <p class="slds-truncate" title={contact.Phone}>{contact.Phone}</p>
                            </lightning-tile>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </template>
            </template>
        </ul>
    </lightning-card>
</template>`
```

**Java Script**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import getAllContacts from '@salesforce/apex/ContactManager.getContact';

export default class FetchRecordsViaApex2 extends LightningElement {
   @track numberOfRecords;
   @track contacts;

   get responseReceived(){
       if(this.contacts)
       {
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }

   numberOfContactChangeHandler(event)
   {
       this.numberOfRecords=event.target.value;
   }

   getContacts(){
       getAllContacts({numberOfRecords:this.numberOfRecords}).then(response=>
       {this.contacts=response;
       }).catch(error=>{
            console.log('Error in retrieving contact records',error.body.message);
       });
   }


}
```

**Apex Class**

```
public with sharing class ContactManager {

@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
public static List<Contact> getContact(Integer noOfContactRecords){
    System.debug('getContact');
    return [select id, LastName,Phone from Contact limit:noOfContactRecords];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's because your parameter `numberOfRecords` does not exist in your apex class, you must use the same property name when passing, so, inseadt of `numberOfRecords` in your lwc, you must declare `noOfContactRecords`